# What is the geometric interpretation of $|z-1|^2+|z+1|^2=4$ for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

> Show that $|z-1|^2+|z+1|^2=4$ for all z such that $|z|=1$.

[Note that $|z|$ refers to the magnitude of z where $z=a+bi$].

I was able to 'prove' the question; however, I cannot think of a geometric interpretation in the complex plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Geometrically, this is the fact that any angle subtended by a diameter is a right angle.  Indeed, consider the triangle formed by the points $z$, $1$, and $-1$.  Since the segment from $1$ to $-1$ is a diameter of the unit circle, the angle at $z$ is a right angle.  The Pythagorean theorem then says $|z-1|^2+|z-(-1)|^2=|1-(-1)|^2$, which is just what you've shown.  Conversely, if you know that $|z-1|^2+|z+1|^2=4$, then the law of cosines tells you the angle at $z$ is a right angle.

Answer (score 6):

Look at $-1$ and $1$ as the endpoints of a diameter of the unit circle.
If $z\not\in\{-1,1\}$ lies on the unit circle, the lines joining $1$ and $z$, $-1$ and $z$ are orthogonal, i.e. the triangle having $1,-1,z$ as vertices is a right triangle. By the Pythagorean theorem,
$$ \|1-z\|^2 + \|-1-z\|^2 = 2^2 = 4.$$

Answer (score 5):

I'd only want to illustrate the other answers.

[image]